# What is this USA membership pin?

Tags: united-states, identification

The attached picture shows what is believed to be a membership pin. Is it possible to identify the organization?

The pin is from the USA and dates from the period 1890-1914. A possibility is that it is from either North or South Dakota, but this is uncertain.

[image: Membership pin - gold colored stickpin with a moose or elk]

Comment: Perhaps [Benevolent and Protective Order of Elks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_and_Protective_Order_of_Elks): [Sample 1](https://www.rubylane.com/item/161834-25395/Vintage-Elk-Pin-30-Year-BPOE?search=1) and [Sample 2](https://www.rubylane.com/item/338449-RL6805/Victorian-ELKS-Lodge-BPOE-Tooth-Pendant?search=1)

Comment: Seems to be a possibility, but I have not been able to find a similar pin with connection to the order (or even finding a similar pin). The time for when the pin was obtained has been narrowed down to 1901-1913.

Comment: Lacks detailed verbose description for the blind and vision impaired.

Comment: @samuelRussel Is there a reason to not edit the question to include verbose description for the visually impaired?

Answer (score 2):

Because of the [palmate antlers](https://bearwitnessjacksonhole.com/difference-moose-elk/), this looks more like is called a moose rather than what is called an elk, in the U.S. There is a fraternal organization called the [Loyal Order of the Moose](https://www.mooseintl.org/loyal-order-of-moose/) that was founded in 1888 in Louisville, Kentucky, but now exists all across the U.S. as well as in some Canadian provinces and parts of Great Britain.

There is/was a vintage [Fraternal Order of Moose lapel pin](http://web.archive.org/web/20200805043551/http://www.handmedownhaven.com/product/JPB10017) for sale, so you can see what moose jewelry looks like. Etsy has a page devoted to [moose lapel pins](https://www.etsy.com/market/moose_lapel_pin) in general, among which is a "[vintage moose head stick pin](http://web.archive.org/web/20201114002737/https://www.etsy.com/listing/477473917/vintage-moose-head-stick-pin)" that somewhat resembles the one you have, except it's facing the other direction.

Comment: If you had a bit more rep you would see a deleted answer which shows many moose pins and buttons from the Bull Moose Party circa 1912. The user self deleted that answer when it was pointed out that *none* of his nine images resembled the above pin. He concluded 'this doesn't have the neck bump, nor the right horns, So I'm removing my answer '...

Comment: Yeah, I debated leaving as a comment instead of an answer, but (a) that's an inappropriate use of comments, and (b) even a partial answer is better than no answer. The picture in the OP is at a weird angle and obscures some details of the antlers.